# Plugin Deactivate Self on Activation Errors

Tags: plugins, themes, activation, deactivation, deactivated-plugin

Hi I'm wondering if someone can point me in the right direction here. I'm having trouble figuring out how deactivate_plugins() works. I've been using variations of the below for awhile now and it's always seemed to work until recently.

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_plugin_activate_deactivate');
add_action('after_switch_theme', 'my_plugin_activate_deactivate');

function my_plugin_activate_deactivate() {
    if ( !function_exists ('mythemename') {
      deactivate_plugins( plugin_basename(__FILE__) );
    }
}
```

The first problem is that the `register_activation_hook` part doesn't do anything at all... the plugin activates regardless of whether or not mythemename function exists.

I even tried just doing this, but the plugin still activates.

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_plugin_activate_deactivate');

function my_plugin_activate_deactivate() {
      deactivate_plugins( plugin_basename(__FILE__) );
}
```

Even worse though using the `after_switch_theme` part throws a 500 server error, when switching themes and it takes manually disabling the plugin through ftp/sftp.

My goal is to have a "theme functionality plugin" that checks if the theme is active and if not deactivates itself. What am I missing here? Something obvious? I feel like there's a spelling error or something stupid because this has always seemed to work in the past...

**Update :** I activated an error log on the server and am getting this error about [deactivate_plugins()](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/d01e8db4adced4f82239ce8ec8f2cc2bf6a4c6d3/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php#L638):

```
Call to undefined function deactivate_plugins() in /path/to/plugin/plugin-name.php on line 25
```

Answer (score 2):

You may need to have this line in your code

```
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );
```

The plugin.php file is not automatically included.

Comment: I've seen this used a couple times, but not really sure why. Do you know why that's necessary?

Comment: @BryanWillis The function `deactivate_plugins` is defined in that file. Hence we use it.